# Problem calling labelname.Text in my source code

Tags: c#, wpf, label

I am very new to WPF in C# and I am stuck working on an application made to (among other things) calculate the total number of items on a list. I want to print a label with that number/the sum and in tutorials I have seen people call `labelname.Text` in their source code, but when I try to do the same I don't have that option.

[My Windows application design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJKUQ.png)

It is in Danish, but what I need is the sum of "Antal" from the table printed on a label next to "Samlet antal varer:" to the right of the table.

My DataGrid:

```xml
    <DataGrid ColumnWidth="*" CanUserAddRows="False" x:Name="StockList" Margin="57,23,453,261">
            <!--Column Header Text & Bindings -->
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vare" Binding="{Binding vare}" Width="auto"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pris" Binding="{Binding pris}" Width="50"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Antal" Binding="{Binding antal}" Width="50"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Samlet pris" Binding="{Binding samletPris}"  Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

My Labels:

```xml
    <!-- labels -->
        <Label x:Name="lblSamletVarer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="637,142,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblSamletPrisEkskl"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="637,192,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblSamletPrisInkl"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="637,242,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

I hope it all makes sense. Please reach out if you need more information in order to help.

Comment: I suspect that `labelname` is the name of a control / HTML element.  You won't be able to reference it (or its Text attribute) unless you also have a control with that name.

Comment: There is no `x:Name=labelname` to use it like `labelname.Text`, you can set the text using `lblSamletVarer.Text`

Comment: A label in wpf is actually a content control. It has no text property. It has a content property. The equivalent to a html label in wpf is a textblock. If you set the content of a label to a string then something counter intuitive happens. The label creates a textblock as it's content and sets that textblock's text property to your string. You should probably be using textblocks rather than labels.

Comment: @aki could you please share code-behind where you actually using that statement (labelname.Text)?

Comment: How would seeing code help?  There is no text property on a label.  It has content. Set Content instead of Text. Or use a textblock instead of label.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. I followed Andy's advice using textblocks instead of labels and it seems to be working :) I have, however, encountered a new problem, so I will be making another post.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Label1" Text="{Binding Path=Label1Value}"/>
```

in XAML to replace your label markup (a better option than a Label) then provide a value for it in your ViewModel or code-behind; you can provide a literal value as I've shown below or use whatever logic you like to compute a value at runtime and return that.  A TextBlock uses a OneWay binding by default since it is read-only, so you don't need to provide a setter or PropertyChanged notification.

```
public string Label1Value
{
  get { return "This string in your TextBlock"; }
}
```

Obviously, use whatever more appropriate identifiers you like for "Label1Value" and "Label1"!

It isn't clear what you are trying to bind the DataGridTextColumn elements to in your code.  You can bind directly from one control to another using the "ElementName" syntax within the binding expression, but since you need to compute something from your DataGridTextColumn, I assume you'll bind that to something in your ViewModel or code-behind and calculate the value there before passing it back.